# How to add a class to the last element in a submenu

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a multilevel menu. I need the **li** element to have a custom class in the first nesting level. In this menu, there will be other nestings inside the first level of nesting, but I only need the last **li** element to have a custom class in the first level. How can i do this?
Now I have a code that adds a class to the last **li** element at the top level.

```js
function wpb_first_and_last_menu_class($items)
{
    $items[count($items)]->classes[] = 'last';
    return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'wpb_first_and_last_menu_class');
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more your question?

Comment: My question is how can I add a class to the last element in the first nesting level

Comment: Show input and expected output in a much clear manner.